# Python how to iterate two infinite generators at the same time？

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'd like to iterate over a number of infinite generators:

```
def x(y):
    while True:
        for i in xrange(y):
            yield i

for i,j in zip(x(5),x(3)):
    print i,j
```

The code above will will produce nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you just do it in two separate threads?

Comment: `from itertools import izip as zip`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: or `from future_builtins import zip`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because Python 2 `zip` tries to create a list by getting all the elements the generator will ever produce. What you want is an iterator, i.e.  `itertools.izip`.

In Python 3 `zip` works like `izip`.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is not the right tool for generators. Try `itertools.izip` instead!

(Or even better, use Python 3, where your code works fine - once you add parentheses to the `print`)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a variant of `zip` that returns an iterator instead of a list. Fortunately, there's one of them in the `itertools` module.

```
import itertools

def x(y):
    while True:
        for i in xrange(y):
            yield i

for i,j in itertools.izip(x(5),x(3)):
    print i,j
```

Note that in Python 3, `itertools.izip` doesn't exist because the vanilla `zip` is already an iterator.

---

Also in `itertools` there's a function called [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) which infinitely cycles over an iterable.

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the
>   saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.

So `itertools.cycle(range(5))` does the same thing as your `x(5)`; you can also pass `xrange(5)` to `cycle`, it's not fussy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are trying to iterate over two iterators simultaneously. You can always use while loop if nothing else works.

```
gen1 = x(5)
gen2 = x(3)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(gen1), next(gen2))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

If you using python3.4 and above, then your function x can be refactored too-

```
def x(y):
     yield from xrange(y)
```